# Paste as values vs Paste as text

Tags: microsoft-excel

Does anyone know the technical explanation behind the difference between the two copy/paste methods below?

> 1. Copy and paste special - values (within the same instance of excel)
> 2. Copy and paste special - text (between separate instances of excel)

A little background: I'm working with an excel sheet that requires users to load in several table of data each week from system outputs (not consistently formatted outputs) - so there is a lot of copy and paste activity.  The current m.o. is to only do so from a separate instance of excel, otherwise errors can occur (i.e. a vendor code of 000025 might get converted to 25).

I can literally take a cell with a numeric value, copy and paste it using the 2 methods listed above into the same sheet, and they do not get recognized as being the same contents.

[image: screenshot of an example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste as values will paste the value. If it's text, it remains as text, if it's a number, it remains a number.

Paste as text will convert the value to text. text will remain text, but a number pasted as text will not be interpreted as a number by Excel, but as a string.

Try using `=C3=VALUE(C4)`

Comment: based on the screen shot above, pasting as text its a number, and pasting as value kept it a string...Assuming no special formatting was applied to the cells.  Number will justify to the right by default...at least in North America.

Comment: thanks - that is a helpful explanation.  I understand how the value() function will help resolve many of the issues, however I'm wondering if there is a way to duplicate the paste as text process without having to do so from a separate instance of excel (even if it involves VBA).

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202074/vba-convert-string-to-int-if-string-is-a-number) may be of interest